# Wrong subquery in my SQL query

Tags: sql, subquery, logic

https://screenshot.googleplex.com/j4igYFL9sjH
Find the printer makers also producing PCs with the lowest RAM capacity and the highest processor speed of all PCs having the lowest RAM capacity. 
Result set: maker.

My Query:

```
SELECT maker FROM Product WHERE type ='Printer' AND model IN(SELECT DISTINCT(model), hd, ram FROM PC 
                        WHERE hd = (
                                SELECT MAX(hd) FROM PC 
                                     WHERE model IN(SELECT DISTINCT(model) FROM PC
                                                                       WHERE ram <=(SELECT MIN(ram) FROM PC))));
```

It turns out there is no maker list in this. I think there is something wrong with the subquery.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results... There's no way you need all those subqueries...  Also, which database are you using -- that could affect the answer.

Comment: http://sql-ex.ru/help/select13.php#db_1

Comment: Here: `WHERE type ='Printer' AND model` you need to find a maker, not a model, so it should be: `WHERE type ='Printer' AND maker IN...`

Comment: re: *..producing PCs with the lowest RAM capacity and the highest processor speed of all PCs having the lowest RAM capacity* ??? not very clear what come first..

Answer (score 5):

I really don't like this question because it's so ambiguously worded. Hopefully this will save someone else the headache I just went through figuring out what is being asked:

```
SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM Product WHERE type = 'printer' AND maker IN 
  ( SELECT maker FROM Product WHERE model IN ( 
       SELECT model FROM Pc 
          WHERE ram = (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM PC)   
          AND speed = (SELECT MAX( speed) FROM 
             (SELECT speed FROM Pc WHERE 
                 ram = (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM Pc)) as z4) 
             )
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problems**

1. There is no guarantee that PC `maker` with a given category also producing printers..current query not anticipate that so it could return noting
2. The current sub query is insufficient for the problem, the whole query not work because the sub query returning `model` of a PC with min RAM, max Processor, max hard-disk and whatever, and then that model compared to all printer's `model` in `product`..so it will never find any match..

**Solution**

1. *Flip* the query so the main query become sub query and vice versa, so sub query is about getting all printer `maker`
2. Once flipped, getting PC-printer `maker` with any condition is easy, just use `order by`..

**The Code**

this code bellow return a printer `maker` that also make PC with biggest `hd` and smallest `ram`

```
SELECT maker FROM product A INNER JOIN PC B ON A.model = B.model 
WHERE maker IN (SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM product WHERE type = 'printer')
ORDER BY hd DESC, ram ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer, hope it can be helpful to you

```
SELECT distinct maker FROM product WHERE type = 'printer'
AND maker IN (SELECT maker
FROM product JOIN ( 
SELECT model, speed, ram FROM pc WHERE speed =
                (SELECT MAX(speed) FROM pc
                WHERE ram = (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc)
                ) 
            AND ram = (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc)
            ) b
ON product.model = b.model)
```

By using:

```
SELECT model, speed, ram FROM pc WHERE speed = 
(SELECT MAX(speed) FROM pc 
WHERE ram = (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc))
```

you made sure it will return anything with the speed of 100.
Say you have model 1,2,3, their speeds are all 100 but their rams are different, it will return all three models while really just model 1 has the lowest ram. So you want to add

```
AND ram = (SELECT MIN(ram) FROM pc)
```

as an additional condition to make sure the requirement on ram does not go away when you take models by using the pc standard.

Comment: I think this question is really triki, because really reading the question: "producing PCs with the lowest RAM capacity and the highest processor speed of all PCs" I understand to get the one with lowest RAM of all and the same time the highest processor which could be stated as: `where ram = (select min(ram) from pc)
    and speed = (select max(speed) from pc)` and then not result would be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct maker
from product
where 
 model in (
select model 
from  (select * from pc where ram in (select min (ram) from pc)) as A
where speed in 

(select max(speed) from
          (select * from pc  where ram in (select min(ram) from pc ))      as B)
)
and maker in (select maker  from product where type like 'printer')
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a divide and conquer approach

```
WITH pc_lowest_ram as (
  SELECT DISTINCT model, pc.ram FROM pc
  WHERE pc.ram = (
   SELECT MIN(ram) FROM PC
  )
),
printer_makers AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT maker FROM product p
  WHERE p.type = 'Printer'
),
pc_max_speed AS (
  SELECT MAX(speed) pm FROM pc
  JOIN pc_lowest_ram plr on (plr.model = pc.model)
  WHERE plr.ram = pc.ram
),
pc_models AS (
  SELECT pc.model pm FROM pc
  JOIN pc_lowest_ram plr on (plr.model = pc.model)
  WHERE plr.ram = pc.ram
  AND pc.speed = (
    SELECT pm FROM pc_max_speed
  )
)
SELECT DISTINCT p.maker FROM product p
JOIN printer_makers ON (printer_makers.maker = p.maker)
JOIN pc_models ON (pc_models.pm = p.model)
```